# Selecionar campo no WebBrowser

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

preciso acessar esse site https://free-proxy-list.net/  e selecionar a opção de porta 8080. Alguma dica?

Abs

Comment: você quer, no select que tem ao final da página, escolher a opção 8080 correto ? tem uma dificuldade aí que o elemento não possui id ou name mas vamos tentar

Comment: Você quer copiar o ip na linha aonde esta a porta 8080 para uma string?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Quero usar o select no final da pagina e escolher a porta 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui selecionar o valor que você precisa, apesar do `select` não ter id, fiz um "pog" pra validar pelo `InnerText` mas, o site ainda não aplicou o valor selecionado à lista, não consegui identificar o que dispara o filtro.

Segue o código:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://free-proxy-list.net/");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var colecao = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.All.Cast<HtmlElement>().ToList();
        HtmlElement elemento = colecao.Find(p => p.TagName.ToLower() == "select" && p.InnerText.StartsWith("All"));
        elemento.SetAttribute("value", "8080");
    }
}
```

Comment: aqui nao funcionou. Deu erro "Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto." na linha elemento.SetAttribute("value", "8080");

Comment: coloca pra depurar, um breakpoint, e veja se a variavel "elemento" não está nula... confira o evento do wb, tem de ser o "documentCompleted"

Comment: Código alterado, aqui também havia parado de funcionar, tente novamente

Comment: a variável "elemento" está nula

Comment: Agora o combo aparece selecionado com "8080", porem não aplica o filtro

Comment: sim, foi o que escrevi e não consegui fazer, pois não encontrei o que dispara o filtro